# Exception while running hive support on Spark: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

Hello i am trying use Hive with spark but when i try executing, it shows this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate SparkSession with Hive support because Hive classes are not found.
```

This is my source code

```
package com.spark.hiveconnect

import java.io.File

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}

object sourceToHIve {
  case class Record(key: Int, value: String)
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Hive Example")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    import spark.sql

    sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
    sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/usr/local/spark3/examples/src/main/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")
    sql("SELECT * FROM src").show()

    spark.close()
  }
}
```

This is my build.sbt file.

```
name := "SparkHive"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"
```

And i also have hive running in the console.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Major Problem is that the class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf" can not be loaded.
you can insert ther following code for testing.

```
Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf",true,
            Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader);
```

And an error will occur in this line.

To be exactly,the fundament problem is your pom may not support hive on spark.
you may check the following dependency.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf" locates in this dependcy.